# Constructor initializing another contract

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have a contract which is creating an instance of another contract. I am confused about deploying the contracts in Truffle. Does the constructor get initialized when deployed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constructors are always executed exactly once when a contract is created.

You'll use Truffle to migrate the factory contract, and then use a function in the factory to deploy created contracts. No need to migrate the contract the factory is designed to deploy. If the constructor of the contract to be deployed needs any arguments, then they should be passed in by the factory.

It's not exactly the same question, but this example might clarify the pattern: [How to migrate a contract that has a constructor parameter of address type via truffle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10973/how-to-migrate-a-contract-that-has-a-constructor-parameter-of-address-type-via-t/10992#10992)

You can structure it like this:

Factory.sol

```
import "Created.sol";

contract Factory {

  function createContract() returns(address created) {
    Created c = new Created(msg.sender); // passing an arg to constructor
    return c;
...
```

./migrations/2_deployFactory.js

```
...
deployer.deploy(Factory);
```

With Truffle, Factory.deployed() will be the contract on the blockchain.

app.js

```
...

var factory = Factory.deployed();
factory.createContract({from: .. })
.then(function(txn) {
  // you have the transaction hash now
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: That's great thanks. I'm having trouble actually using the createdContract in Truffle. Do you know how to use the contract once you have the txn?

Comment: Have a look here. I'm pointing at Xavier's function that waits for the txnhash to be mined. After it's mined, the return values (address?) will be visible. http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/optimal-way-of-waiting-for-transactions-to-be-mined-in-geth/10909#10909

Comment: Ok I was able to get it working using a call() to get the address, once it was mined.

Comment: Cool. You can use the gettransactionReceiptMined() function to wait/(know when) the transactions was mined, and then use call(). Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is going to be to have `Created C;` declared as a public var on the factory contract. Then, after you've deployed the factory, you can access the public var with web3 and use the `Created.at(createdAddress)` syntax to bind that address to the ABI for the Created contract.